# DialogFragment trying to open after coming back from the background

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm showing a DialogFragment and when the user goes back to the background and then goes back to the app, the dialog is displayed.

Is there a way not to display it when coming back from the background?

I tried this (**EDIT**: moved this from onStop to onPause as some suggested):

```
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (dialogFragment.isVisible()) {
       dialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
```

But got this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null
>   object reference

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using  [dismissAllowingStateLoss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismissAllowingStateLoss())

```
dialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of:

```
dialogFragment.dismiss();
```

However this should be required since you are dismissing it in the `onStop()`. You should try to dismiss it inside the `onPause()`.

Comment: Also  with dismissAllowingStateLoss ?

Comment: Yes, since the FragmentTransaction is null, it crashes with NPE

Comment: @Kalisky Did you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` for your transaction? Maybe when you try to show the dialog you use something  like `fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "yourtag");` , but since you are using support library you need `getSupportFragmentManager()`  instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thought about that and made sure it's all getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

Add this method.

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if(dialogFragment != null && dialogFragment.isVisible()) {
                dialogFragment.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better place to hide dialog as in above answer would be onPause().